# What design pattern should I choose?

Tags: design-patterns

If I want to design a navigation system GUI for drivers.

The GUI of the navigation system consists of three components:
A. Map, can be either a satellite map or land Map
B. Destination Location: voice or text location
C. directions. Can be either voice or text

The system works in two modes:
1. Text Mode: land map, text location and text directions
2. Voice Mode: satellite map, voice destination, and voice directions

Which design pattern better to choose for this situation, do you think that the abstract factory will be appropriate?

Comment: See http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/269808/which-design-pattern-is-best-suited/269811#269811

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to answer this question, in a way, by refusing to answer it. Because *you're asking the wrong question*.

Design patterns are a way of categorising various identifiable, um, patterns in code that you write, so as to more easily discuss and compare different pieces of code. They are not something that you set out to use. You don't sit down and go "today, I am going to use the Fuzzlebuzzle Pattern". When you do that, you needlessly constrain yourself to a design before you've even written any code, which is entirely counter-productive. There is simply no benefit to doing so.

Just architect and design your software so that it is easy to read and to maintain, using the abstractions and tools at your disposal. *Then*, perhaps, analyse it and find out whether you've ended up using any existing design patterns. [But otherwise just don't worry about it](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/269811/17853).

The details of what GUI elements will be visible to users in your computer program, and whether your users will be able to run voice commands, are totally irrelevant to this.

Comment: ＋1 for FuzzleBuzzle Pattern.