# Animation Manager design pattern?

Tags: c++, animation, design-patterns, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I have a sprite which has a lot of animations to do on different key press events. 
For example when i press the right arrow key. It will run the following animations:
Startrun, run, Endrun
While the run cycles depends wether or not the key is still being pressed.

I thought about maintaining some kind of an actions queue, and to have a method that will be called each update and just run those actions in order.

In order to stick to a good design. I thought about a fitting design pattern. 
composite? Observer? 
What is the best practice here?

Would really like to hear your thoughts or even some examples.

Thanks
Koby

Comment: Before going to a design pattern (or more of them combined), write a working application. Improve by refactoring and adopting particular design patterns in a second step. There's nothing like a _best practice_ we can recommend, it absolutely depends on your actual requirements (by means of performance, extensibility, etc.)

Comment: please write what do you have so far

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28011208/560648

Comment: I think State Pattern could help: http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/state.html

Comment: @owen thank you that was a great help!

Answer (score 1):

This question is subjective, and every developer will have his flavor of implementation. However I will give my 2 cents about it.

My way (please note the subjective "my" ) would be something like :

- Sprite Manager

  - singleton abstract factory which creates sprites from sprite files
  - also servers as Object pool of sprites
- Sprite

  - composition of sprite frames and Sprite Animation(s)
- Sprite animation

  - aggregation of sprite frames
- GameObject

  - aggregation of sprite , position and other fun stuff
  - has an UpdateFunction called on main loop
- PlayerObject

  - derivation of GameObject
  - state machine implemented in it
- LocalPlayer

  - derivation of PlayerObject
  - registers as observer to InputManager
- RemotePlayer

  - derivation of PlayerObject
  - registers as observer to Socket